# What Nikon DSLR has this colorful user interface on the rear LCD?

Tags: nikon, dslr, camera-controls, lcd, rear-lcd

I have been looking articles for exposure meter tutorial and [this picture](https://yadi.sk/i/_QrtmwOxbhQKqA) caught my eye:

[image: screenshot]

It's truly unusual to see a camera with such colorful rear panel.

What is that camera? How many cameras these days have it especially Nikon D5300? Will my Nikon D80 have that color option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is that camera?

The camera you've pictured appears to be a Nikon D750.

[image]

> How many cameras these days have it especially Nikon D5300?

Well, pretty much all digital SLR cameras have full color screens so that they can display image previews. How much color they use in their menu and control screens is a bit more variable.

This [YouTube video about the D5100](https://youtu.be/aZPiuNjaeRg?t=82) shows the *Information Display* with a similar color background to the image you shared above.

The Information Display screen for the D5300 appears to be a bit more subdued, at least as shown in [this review of the D5300](https://www.photoreview.com.au/reviews/dslr-cameras/advanced/nikon-d5300/).

[image]

**The [Nikon D5300 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/2Pnka00a3Hjt04DYIAO00pxxNF72/D5300VRRM_(En)04.pdf), page 197, shows several display options for the Information Display screen, though.** In addition to the "classic" option shown above, there are six "graphic" display options, three of which appear to be similar to the example you showed from the D750. Unfortunately, the manual is in grayscale, so the actual color schemes of each option can not be determined from the illustrations in the manual.

[image]

[image]

> Will my Nikon D80 have that color option?

Earlier Nikon DSLRs like your 80D did not offer this *Information Display* option on the rear LCD screen when shooting with the viewfinder. Most of the same information was displayed on the monochrome 'Control Screen' located on the top of the camera body. When one delves into the actual menu options with the newer cameras, they look more similar to your Nikon D80's menus as they are displayed on the color rear LCD screen.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best photo I've ever taken, but this photo of the D5300 menu shows the previews of the six available options for its Info screen:

[image: Photo of the camera interface]

Comment: It will be perfect if you show us graphic menus too

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean, but I think you've misinterpreted a label as a title. The top row are the "classic" options and the bottom row are the "graphic" options.

Comment: I remember each of them having different pages

Comment: Also I knew they looked different but wanted to be sure